# Files locked after running a Python script

Tags: qgis, python, lock

I can run a Python script that uses qgsVectorLayer, qgsRasterLayer and many functions like processing:runalg("qgis.difference"......) and os.popen("gdalwarp -q -cutline.......)
but if I want to run it another time, I must close QGIS first and reload it (error: file locked because used by other programs...)
I want to close files handlers but I don't know which ones.
What can I do in this case?

Here is my some of my code
[image]
[image]

Comment: To help you better, can you add your code?

Comment: @FranRaga I edited my question , I added some of my code

Comment: Please, add code not a screenshot.

Comment: When I copy paste my code here it lose its layout and it become hard to read it

Comment: What version of qgis are you using?

Comment: qgis version : 2.14.12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Releasing PyQGIS file locks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77218/releasing-pyqgis-file-locks)

Comment: The simplest way to format your code is to copy/paste it in as text, highlight it and then click the Format button (**{}**).