# Run QGIS tool from standalone Python keeps locks on files

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, standalone, lock

I have a Python application that runs some QGIS processing tools.  The tools are called in a loop and I am looking to clean up the tool outputs (shapefiles) in between each iteration.  I have found that only a call to qgs.exitQgis() releases the locks on the shapefile (the output of the snap process).  But if I try to do further processing or try to initialize QGIS again, the Python execution stops, no exception.  I have tried permutations of this but it seems any calls to QGIS or processing after qgs.exitQgis() stops the execution.

I assume it is the layer registry that has a lock on the shapefile and that exitQgis clearing of the layer registry is releasing the lock.  I also suspect clearing the provider registry breaks everything else...

How can I release the lock so I can delete the intermediate files.  (Some intermediate layers are inputs to OGR processes, so I don't want to create them in memory, I want to be able to open them as OGR layers).

I got this far looking at [Using QGIS Processing algorithms from PyQGIS standalone scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis-processing-algorithms-from-pyqgis-standalone-scripts-outside-of-gui) and other posts on StackExchange.

```
import os
import sys
import stat
import shutil
from osgeo import gdal #used for other things not in this sample
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsProcessingFeedback, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3\apps\qgis\bin", True)

#sys.path.append('C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.30.3/apps/qgis/python/plugins') #this is handled in a shell or batch script calling this py
import processing 
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

def delFolder(folder):
     def on_rm_error(_action, path, _exc):
              os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
              os.remove(path)

     if os.path.exists(folder) and os.path.isdir(folder):
          shutil.rmtree(folder, onerror=on_rm_error)
          print(f'removed directory {folder}')

def main():
     try:        
         
          qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
          qgs.initQgis()
          Processing.initialize()
          inputlayer =r'C:/temp/temp/inputPoly.shp'
          outputPath = r'C:/temp/temp/tmp'
          snaplayer=r'C:/temp/temp/tmp/polysnap.shp'
          dissolvelayer=r'C:/temp/temp/tmp/polydiss.shp'

          os.makedirs(outputPath, exist_ok = True)
     
          print("snap")
          processing.run("native:snapgeometries", {'INPUT':inputlayer,'REFERENCE_LAYER':inputlayer,'TOLERANCE':1,'BEHAVIOR':0,'OUTPUT':snaplayer})
          print('snapped')
     
          print('dissolve')
          processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':snaplayer,'FIELD':['POLY_TYPE'],'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':True,'OUTPUT':dissolvelayer})
          print('dissolved')

          Processing.deinitialize() #tried with and without this
          qgs.exitQgis() #releases the snap lock, the dissolved shapefile doesn't seem locked at all
          #qgs.exit() #doesn't seem to make a difference for the lock
       
          print(f'try to delete temp folder {outputPath}')
          delFolder(outputPath)

          #do the same processing for the sake of the test  
          os.makedirs(outputPath, exist_ok = True)
          print(f"{outputPath} made")
          
          qgs.initQgis()  #script ends here, tried creating a new qgs but I think it is singleton
          print('qgsApp initialized')
          Processing.initialize() #tried with and without
          print('processing initialized')

          #do again for test
          print("snap")
          processing.run("native:snapgeometries", {'INPUT':inputlayer,'REFERENCE_LAYER':inputlayer,'TOLERANCE':1,'BEHAVIOR':0,'OUTPUT':snaplayer})
          print('snapped')
         
          print('dissolve')
          processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':snaplayer,'FIELD':['POLY_TYPE'],'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':True,'OUTPUT':dissolvelayer})
          print('dissolved')

          Processing.deinitialize()
          qgs.exitQgis()
          qgs.exit()

          print(f'try to delete temp folder {outputPath}')
          delFolder(outputPath)
     
     except Exception as e:
          print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Releasing PyQGIS file locks?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77218/releasing-pyqgis-file-locks)

Comment: Your code is not PEP8-compliant. You should only use *four* spaces as the indent. More (or less) makes the code less readable and incompatible with pasting into other code.

Answer (score 2):

Ok more reading and tinkering I found a solution so I will post it for others.  I had to create the QgsVectorLayers and add them to the QgsProject and remove all the layers from the QgsProject.  I also had to get the ProcessingContext from the process and temporaryLayerStore().removeAllMapLayers().  Not sure it was necessary to do all the layers and all the processing contexts but I see no downside to doing each one.  This avoided using exitQgis() before I wanted to.

```
print("snap")
          snapcontext  = QgsProcessingContext()
          processing.run("native:snapgeometries", {'INPUT':inputlayer,'REFERENCE_LAYER':inputlayer,'TOLERANCE':1,'BEHAVIOR':0,'OUTPUT':snaplayer}, context=snapcontext)
          print('snapped')
     
          disscontext = QgsProcessingContext()
          print('dissolve')
          processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':snaplayer,'FIELD':['POLY_TYPE'],'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':True,'OUTPUT':dissolvelayer}, context=disscontext)
          print('dissolved')

   
          lyrSnap = QgsVectorLayer(snaplayer, 'snaplayer', 'ogr' )
          lyrDiss = QgsVectorLayer(dissolvelayer, 'disslayer', 'ogr' )
          QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyrSnap) #this is the layer that had the lock
          QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyrDiss) #found this was unnecessary but I think if the dissolve layer was an input to something else it would
            
          QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
          QgsProject.instance().clear()
          del lyrSnap, lyrDiss #works without this but examples showed doing this...

          snapcontext.temporaryLayerStore().removeAllMapLayers() #this didn't seem to fix it, I think the lock is caused by being an input to the dissolve, if I was trying to remove the input to snap, this might do it
          disscontext.temporaryLayerStore().removeAllMapLayers() # this removed the lock

          print(f'try to delete temp folder {outputPath}')
          delFolder(outputPath)
```